# mousemove and mouseover is not working for the last data in d3 chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

In my D3 chart mousemove and mouseover is not working for the last data as depicted in pic attached.

It's  always showing the tooltip upto second last element. I have data for last one also but it shows mousemove and mouseover only upto second last element (line and circle) in chart.

[image]
Data -

```
var data = [
      {
        startTime: "1567765320049",
        magnitude: 0
      },
      {
        startTime: "1567851720049",
        magnitude: 0
      },
      {
        startTime: "1568024520049",
        magnitude: 10
      },
      {
        startTime: "1568283720049",
        magnitude: 10
      },
      {
        startTime: "1568629320049",
        magnitude: 0
      },
      {
        startTime: "1569061320049",
        magnitude: 0
      },
      {
        startTime: "1569579720049",
        magnitude: -20
      },
      {
        startTime: "1570184520049",
        magnitude: -20
      },
      {
        startTime: "1570875720049",
        magnitude: 0
      },
      {
        startTime: "1571653320049",
        magnitude: 10
      },
      {
        startTime: "1572517320049",
        magnitude: 0
      },
      {
        startTime: "1573467720049",
        magnitude: 0
      },
      {
        startTime: "1574504520049",
        magnitude: 10
      },
      {
        startTime: "1575627720049",
        magnitude: 10
      }
    ];
```

I have a working code sandbox here -

https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-bell-qqwwe

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed this issue, I am getting which date value is closest to the mouse and displaying in tooltip.

```
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        focus.style("display", null);
        div
            .transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 0.9);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        focus.style("display", "none");
        div
            .transition()
            .duration(300)
            .style("opacity", 0);
    })

    .on("mousemove", function() {
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        var mouseDate = xScale.invert(mouse[0]);
        var i = bisectDate(data, mouseDate); // returns the index to the current data item

        var d0 = data[i - 1];
        var d1 = data[i];
        let d;
        // work out which date value is closest to the mouse
        if (typeof d1 !== "undefined") {
            d = mouseDate - d0.startTime > d1.startTime - mouseDate ? d1 : d0;
        } else {
            d = d0;
        }

        div
            .html(
                `<span>${parseDate(d.startTime)}</span>
                 <span>Magnitude: ${d.magnitude} </span>`
            )
            .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
            .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 28 + "px");
        var x = xScale(d.startTime);
        var y = yScale(d.magnitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shift the overlay rectangle `width/2` to the left:

```
 g.selectAll("dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("x", (d) => xScale(d.startTime) - width/2)  //<<<<< new line
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    focus.style("display", null);
    div
```

[Updated code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-hermann-5xd3n)

Comment: after adding your line I removed the calculation I was doing in 'mousemove' for d but its not working properly. tooltip doesn't come close to mouse.